# Correct way to use Lookahead and Lookbehind with RegEx to filter a list

Tags: regex

I have a list containing some names from an input field which all meet the conditions in the following Regex:

```
    ^([A-Za-z']*)+$|^([A-Za-z']*[ |-]?[A-Za-z]*)+$
```

BUONAROTTI SIMONI
DALI i DOMENECH
NIETZSCHE
O'COILEAIN AKA COLLINS
O'COILEAIN ALSO COLLINS
O'COILEAIN KNOWN AS COLLINS
O'COILEAIN ALSO KNOWN AS COLLINS
PAYNE-GAPOSCHKIN
TOULOUSE-LAUTREC-MONFA
VAN EYCK

However, I need to identify the names in the list containing the following unwanted phrases within the string (Case-insensitive):

> **AKA, was, also, Also known as, Known as, Previously**

I have tried the following Regexes without success, I just can't seem to get my head around `Lookarounds` in Regex

```
^(?>!( WAS )|( AKA )|( KNOWN AS )|( PREVIOUSLY )|( ALSO )[A-Za-z']*)+$|^(?>!( WAS )|( AKA )|( KNOWN AS )|( PREVIOUSLY )|( ALSO )[A-Za-z']*[ |-]?[A-Za-z]*)+$

^[A-Za-z']*)+(?>!( WAS )|( AKA )|( KNOWN AS )|( PREVIOUSLY )|( ALSO )$|^[A-Za-z']*[ |-]?[A-Za-z]*)+(?>!( WAS )|( AKA )|( KNOWN AS )|( PREVIOUSLY )|( ALSO )$

^(?<!( WAS )|( AKA )|( KNOWN AS )|( PREVIOUSLY )|( ALSO )[A-Za-z']*)+$|^(?<!( WAS )|( AKA )|( KNOWN AS )|( PREVIOUSLY )|( ALSO )[A-Za-z']*[ |-]?[A-Za-z]*)+$

^[A-Za-z']*)(?<!( WAS )|( AKA )|( KNOWN AS )|( PREVIOUSLY )|( ALSO )+$|^[A-Za-z']*[ |-]?[A-Za-z]*)+(?<!( WAS )|( AKA )|( KNOWN AS )|( PREVIOUSLY )|( ALSO )$
```

Please can somebody point me in the right direction with Lookarounds (either Lookahead or Lookbehind). Thanks in advance for any/all advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pattern `^([A-Za-z']*)+$|^([A-Za-z']*[ |-]?[A-Za-z]*)+$` all the parts are optional so it could also match an empty string.

You can omit one of the alternations by optionally repeating the second part and matching at least 1 or more characters with the character class using `+`

```
^[A-Za-z']+(?:[ -][A-Za-z]+)*$
```

If you want to identify the unwanted phrases, you don't need lookarounds. You can match one of the unwanted alternatives between optional parts allowing only your specified characters in the character classes.

You can omit the `|` from the character class if you don't meant to match a pipe char `[ -]`

```
^(?:[A-Za-z']+(?:[ -][A-Za-z]+)* )?(?:AKA|was|Also(?: known as)?|Known as|Previously)(?: [A-Za-z']+(?:[ -][A-Za-z]+)*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vgWEUE/1)

The other way around could be to exclude the match using a negative lookahead, only allowing to match if one of the alternatives is not present.

```
^(?!.*(?:AKA|was|Also(?: known as)?|Known as|Previously))[A-Za-z']+(?:[ -][A-Za-z]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LTZqf/1)

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor for the superb response, very elegant and brilliantly explained. I'm very grateful. Thanks also for spotting the redundant pipe character in the character class. I like how you've also demonstrated the results of both options. Do you offer Regex tutorials? I'd gladly sign up on your course.

Comment: @Ifte You are welcome. There are good tutorials online like https://www.regular-expressions.info/ and https://www.rexegg.com/ and Wiktor Stribiżew has a lot of [great regex video's](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw/videos)

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't know about these videos. Must have a browse of this goldmine. I'm still learning Regex and I find it fascinating as it's pure Algebra. Thanks again

Comment: @Ifte This one regex master is **not** Wiktor, he's *The 4th Bird* :p

Comment: Thanks @bobblebubble for pointing that out, I was just about to go to bed when I wrote those comments 

Thanks Thefourthbird also for providing the original elegant answers and the links to Wiktor's tutorials. I'd still be interested in learning more real-world Regex from great masters like yourselves and will happily subscribe to your tutorial channels. Much obliged to you all. Have a happy and safe New Year everyone 